# onAppear not working until TabView changed

Tags: swift, swiftui, loading

My code works fine when I switch between `TabViews` and the `onAppear` is able to do the background functions to do calculations.
However when my App loads the `MainTabView` the `onAppear` doesn't work and the data shown is empty.

`AuthView` which runs once the user is authenticated:

```
NavigationView {
                MainTabView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
            .onAppear {
                let authUser = try? AuthService.shared.getAuthenticatedUser()
                self.showSignInView = authUser == nil
                homeViewModel.fetchAll()
            }
```

MainTabView:

```
NavigationView {
            TabView {
                    HomeView(viewModel: HomeViewModel())
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
                        }
                    ListView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Absences", systemImage: "image")
                        }
                    SettingsView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                        }
                    }
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, darkModeEnabled ? .dark : .light)
                    .accentColor(AppColor.green)
            }
        .onAppear{
            print("loaded")
            homeViewModel.fetchAll()
        }
```

However is seems that `homeViewModel.fetchAll()` is not run before this and the data isn't retrieved when the App is closed and re-opened

This is the same if the `ListView` is opened first, only when I manually switch between tabs does the view update.

I'm running `SwiftUI`, is the a way to refresh the pages?

Thanks

Comment: It seems likely that you have two instances of `HomeViewModel` - One in `AuthView` and one in `MainTabView` - You should probably be having a single `@StateObject` instance in the environment.

Comment: It seems that you have a problem between sync and async functions. `.onAppear` runs immediately but it doesn't wait to get an answer from the web Auth service; you could try replacing it with `.task`, but it is not possible to say if it will work until we know what `@State` variable should be affected besides `showSignInView`. What does `homeViewModel.fetchAll()` does (or should do) with your view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `onAppear` is it will be called multiple times. It would be better to do your fetch sooner than that anyway, e.g. straight after authentication.

To do this you can create a singleton object called `AppModel` authenticate and fetch all inside its `init`. Pass the model into your View hierarchy using `.environmentObject`, this has the advantage you can use a different singleton when previewing. You'll find this pattern in the Xcode app template when core data is checked.